# How to get by FQL info about more users by ids?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using this query

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2=14xxxx42)
```

to get info about 14xxxx42 user and it works.

How can I get info about for example 3 specific users ? ( user 14xxxx42 and user X and user Y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info about multiple users just run this query:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid in (14xxxx42, 14xxxx43, 14xxxx44)
```